# Does using knockout to render everything make it easier to bind to the dom and vs Rasor view rendering

Tags: razor, knockout.js

I'm using knockout heavily in this app and will be performing lots of manipulation of a javascript view model. Initially I rendered the contents using razor loops over a POCO class, but now I am thinking of getting knockout to render everything (via 2.0 native templates).

This is so that I will be able to bind more effectively to the dom elements and back to the viewmodel. Is this the correct way of thinking?

Answer (score 1):

I have been in this situation before where I have duplicate functionality (rendering html) in razor and in js.  If you are required to render html in your js via ajax and `knockout.js` anyways, than I do not see the benefit of duplicating this functionality in razor.  Instead just reuse your client side code to render the html in js.  Usually I would serialize my poco objects into `JSON` and embed that in the client on inital page load, so the js will create the html based on the objects just as it would when it is return via `AJAX`.

Comment: Yeah,and if I use razor then I don't think it would be easy to wire up the html so that it binds directly to an observable array, like how it would have been done having rendered it with Knockout..

Comment: Yup, I think you are better off keeping that functionality in one place

Comment: +1 I've been doing exactly this in my latest project, works quite well (so far, knock on wood).

Comment: lol, @xec I find a lot of the benefits of Razor and partial views are redundant when I start using knockout..